# substract two columns from two tables in new column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similar tables like this:

```
+-----+------+------+---------------------+
| ID  |  A   |   B  |      Timestamp      | 
| 308 | 1.82 | 1.38 | 2012-08-28 21:17:59 |
| 309 | 1.81 | 1.81 | 2012-08-28 21:18:25 |
| 310 | 1.38 | 1.34 | 2012-08-28 21:18:43 |
+-----+------+------+---------------------+
```

Need to create new table like this:

```
+-----+------+------+---------------------+
| ID  |A1-A2 | B1-B2|      Timestamp      | 
| 308 |  x   |   x  | 2012-08-28 21:17:59 |
| 309 |  x   |   x  | 2012-08-28 21:18:25 |
| 310 |  x   |   x  | 2012-08-28 21:18:43 |
+-----+------+------+---------------------+
```

Has anybody any suggestion for this query or sql cmd ?

#### EDIT

Sorry, my fault, that I didn`t specify it.

I need to substract and sync the tables via timestamp, ID is not needed or important. Both tables are filled every second with 2 numbers ( a, b), timestamp is automatically generated

Its any way to calculating this substract for this 2 tables ontime in cycle ? Output should be like this, and calculating every second, it is possible ?

```
+---------------------+-------+------+
|      Timestamp      |A1-A2  | B1-B2|  
| 2012-08-28 21:17:59 |  x    |   x  |
| 2012-08-28 21:18:25 |  x    |   x  |
| 2012-08-28 21:18:43 |  x    |   x  |
+---------------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Are the IDs identical between tables? What about the timestamps? A sample of what you've tried would help people answer.

Comment: What do A1-A2 and B1-B2 stand for?

Comment: Do you really need an answer for both MySQL *and* SQL Server?

Comment: I guess you could just take any of the answers here and change the join condition from `t1.id = t2.id` to `t1.Timestamp = t2.Timestamp`.

Answer (score 2):

New table is created with the `insert into <your new table name> into` followed by a select statement. I assumed first table is called `t1` and second table `t2`

```
insert into new_table from
select t1.id, (t1.a - t2.a) as a1_a2, (t1.b - t2.b) as b1_b2, t1.timestamp
from t1
join t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)
```

Column headers are used as column name in the new table but must not have a dash in it.

Answer (score 2):

If the ID's are same. You would create you new table and populate it like this

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT t1.id, (t1.a - t2.a), (t1.b - t2.b), t1.timestamp, ....
FROM table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Note that you did not specify what you you wanted to do with the other fields, you have data from both table available now to do with as you please.

Comment: EDIT

sry my fault, that I didn`t specify it..

I need to substract and sync the tables via timestamp, ID is not needed or important

this both tables are filled every second with 2 number ( a, b), timestamp is automaticly generated

Its any way to calculating this substract for this 2 tables ontime in cycle ?

th

Comment: @Chris Whatever your common data is that links the to tables, whether that be id or timestamp, that would be the field you would use as the field you are joining on.  What this allow you to do is have access to the values in both tables to where you can do what you want with them (i.e. subtract them, take the value from one table of the other, etc.)